# How can I get around this node sass incompatibility version error when running npm run dev?

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm

whenever I run `npm run dev` I get this error:

`Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.`

Based on the compatibility list (https://github.com/sass/node-sass) I've tried setting `node-sass` to `6.0.0` it still gives me the same error

I've looked up all the ways to solve this but to no avail, I've literally tried everything under the sun.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

info:
node version - 16.14.0

npm version - 8.3.1

in `package.json`:

```
".devDependencies": {
        "sass-loader": "^7.3.1"
    }

"dependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^7.0.0"
    }
```

Comment: Try ``npm rebuild node-sass ``

Comment: @Alaindeseine tried that, still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at `node-sass` package it appear to be deprecated. You should use `sass` module instead of `node-sass`

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

If you prefer using `node-sass` take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass you will find there tyhat for node16.x you need `node-sass`  6.x

Comment: Yeah, I just tried this.  Now I'm getting `TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function`. .. I'm looking into a solution